# Application On time

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing few issues with my `OnTime`-method in vba. The code is supposed to run every 30 minutes, but somehow it runs a few more times in between. I am assuming this is because several `OnTime`-methods might be running when I reset and rerun the code. So I wanted to kill the on time function but getting error. Here is my code below:

Initial code:

```
Sub autorefresh()
    dim timetorun

    timetorun = Now + TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)

    Application.OnTime timetorun, "manager" 'this runs the macro manager which
                                            'runs several other macros and in
                                            'the end calls this macro again in
                                            'order to reset the timetorun counter
End Sub
```

I revised the below code to reset the ontime if needed.

```
Public timetorun As Date    'so that timetorun can be used in both the functions

Sub autorefresh()

    timetorun = Now + TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
    Application.OnTime timetorun, "manager"

End Sub

Sub killontime()

    Application.OnTime earliesttime:=timetorun, procedure:="manager", schedule:=False   '<~~this line gives the error

End Sub
```

Comment: If the public `timetorun` has been altered by the 'other' function then it cannot be used to cancel the first scheduled macro.

Comment: @Jeeped : It might, but the first issue is that it is declared 2 times in different scopes! ;)

Comment: @R3uK - hmmm... I had inferred that after making it public, it was removed from the sub but you could very well be on to the problem; i.e. if it is also declared within the sub then THAT one is the one being used to set the time, not the public one.

Comment: no guys...in the revised code i will not be declaring timetorun again inside the sub. Sorry for the misunderstanding...hope this clears and looking forward to your help

Comment: @pankajnegi : Did it solve your issue? As it did for me, I guess so and I also guess that you haven't take the tour (plz take a minute : http://stackoverflow.com/tour ) as you haven't accepted the answer (no problem, but just take a few moments to familiarize with SO rules! ;) )

Comment: @ R3uk : I edited my question. I have declared the variable only once.I guess the confusion was because I did not include the complete revised code. Pls have a look  and yes i will be taking the tour now:)

Comment: Does changing `timetorun`'s type to `double` help?

Comment: @eirikdaude : thanks.....that worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all of you... After suggestions from R3uk and eirikdaude, the following code works perfectly:

```
Public timetorun As Double

Sub autorefresh()

  timetorun = Now + TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)

  Application.OnTime timetorun, "manager"

End Sub


Sub killontime()

  Application.OnTime timetorun, "manager", , False

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

**You are declaring `timetorun` 2 times** :

1. one as a Public variable and
2. one as a Local variable in `autorefresh` where you *fill* it, so you'll have an empty `timetorun` in `killontime` and that is why you've got the error

More details in here : [CPearson on OnTime method](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx)

So you code should look like this :

```
Public TimeToRun As Date 'so that timetorun can be used in both the functions

Sub autorefresh()

TimeToRun = Now + TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
'this runs the macro manager which runs several other macros and _
'in the end calls this macro again in order to reset the timetorun counter...

Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "manager"

End Sub

'I added the below code to reset the ontime if needed.
Sub killontime()

Application.OnTime _
    earliesttime:=TimeToRun, _
    procedure:="manager", _
    schedule:=False

End Sub

Sub Manager()

'your code as it is now

'Call autorefresh to reset the OnTime method to another 30 seconds
autorefresh

End Sub
```

Comment: thnx...i have actually decalred it only once .. i guess the way i shared the information was confusing. Pls check the question now. It is basically the same code as what you have suggested..

Comment: And what is you error? On which line? stil the same? (sry for other comment, I thought it was fixed as this works fine for me)

Comment: I get runtime error 1004 : method 'ontime' of object_application failed

Comment: @pankajnegi : I can't reproduce your error, this is working fine for me... What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @ R3uk iam using 2007 version.